# Microsoft.Toolkit.Forms.UI.Controls.WebView: Howto Set Cookies

Tags: c#, winforms, webview, windows-community-toolkit

How to set cookies in the MS-Edge based Microsoft.Toolkit.Forms.UI.Controls.WebView?
I need to send an autentication token cookie to the website I'm navigating to.

What I've tried:

1. Passing a cookie header to the Navigate method: The header won't be passed to the website (verified  by Fiddler). Other headers (like "MyCustomHeader" in the example below) are passed to the site though.

```
string cookieHeader = cookieContainer.GetCookieHeader(siteUri);
var headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
headers.Add("Cookie", "MyAuthCookie=MyAuthToken; Domain=.somesite.net; Path=/");
headers.Add("MyCustomHeader", "MyCustomHeader-Value");
_browser.Navigate(siteUri, HttpMethod.Get, headers: headers);
```

2. Setting the cookie in CookieManager before calling WebView.Navigate:

```
var siteUri = new Uri("http://wwww.somesite.net/");
var filter = new Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
var cookieManager = filter.CookieManager;
var cookie = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpCookie("MyAuthCookie", siteUri.Host, "/");
cookie.Value = "MyAuthToken";
cookieManager.SetCookie(cookie);
webView.Navigate(siteUri);
```

This also does not work when calling NavigateWithHttpRequestMessage Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls.Interop.WinRT.WebViewControlHost (via reflection) instead of WebView.Navigate.

It also does not work when requesting the same URL by HttpClient before calling WebView.Navigate:

```
using (var client = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient(filter) { })
{
    var result = client.GetAsync(siteUri).AsTask().Result;
    result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
}

webView.Navigate(siteUri);
```

That way, the cookie header is only sent with the HttpClient's request, but not with the subsequent WebView.Navigate's request. I guess that the reason for this could be the fact that WebView runs in it's own process.

Is there any way to pass the cookie to the website? Note that the cookie does not originate from the site. The authentication token is retrieved from some other system, and needs to be passed to the website.